# VB.NET: Countdown the Time Selected from Database

Tags: vb.net, countdowntimer

I am making a cyber cafe system where user have to login their own account and i want to use a field "REMAININGTIME" which determines how much time left they have in their own account database. and it will display in the form as lbl.

form will be look like:

**TIME REMAINING: 4 hours 2 minutes**

until it will became 0 hours and 0 minutes.

QUestion: 
what will the "Data Type" of my Field "REMAININGTIME" Is it should be text or data/time?
If i pass the records to a label how can I get it to countdown until zero min and hour?
I already have one timer and it is use for a live clock. Do i have to make another one?

Comment: From all these questions you don't seem to have the required "minimal understanding" but well... the answers are easy: the usual proceeding is relying on the most adequate type (Date or TimeSpan or similar) and generate the corresponding string values from a .ToString conversion. If the values are zero and you don't want to show zero you would have to tell your program to do whatever you want (for example: call a function to generate the string from the time variables with a condition returning what you want when the values are zero)...

Comment: ... the timer is just used (mainly) to call a given method (on the Tick event) every X ms. What you want is values stored in a given variable(s). You can use the same timer to populate as many variables as you wish. Or set different timers if, for example, the Intervals (when the Tick event is triggered) are different. I hope that all your doubts have been solved. Please, use SO as intended: ask specific questions, show what you did (your code) and do some work/research by your own before asking. Questions like this one are usually "awarded" with -1s or an on-hold "badge".